# updated facebook score from iOS app is always zero

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used the following code to update the scores for my game on facebook. The conditions are satisfied for a new score to be updated but when I check the score using Graph API it is always zero.

```
    -(void)postScore:(int)currentScore
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentScore], @"score",
                               nil];
    NSLog(@"Fetching current score");

    (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) ? NSLog(@"session is OPEN") : NSLog(@"session is CLOSED");

    // Get the score, and only send the updated score if it's highter
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/scores", @"xxxx"] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (result && !error) {
            int nCurrentScore = [[[[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
            NSLog(@"Current score is %d", nCurrentScore);
            if (currentScore > nCurrentScore) {
               NSLog(@"Posting new score of %d", currentScore);
               [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/scores", @"xxxx"] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    NSLog(@"Score posted");
                }];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Existing score is higher - not posting new score");
            }
        }

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"the is an error");
        }
    }];
}
```

Checking the score using `GET` `/USER_ID/scores` I get:

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "xxxx",
        "name": "My Name"
      },
      "score": 0,
      "application": {
        "name": "MyApp",
        "id": "xxxx"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For `POST` `/USER_ID/scores` I get:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

The permissions I request for facebook connect in my app:

```
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email", @"public_profile",
                            @"user_friends",@"publish_actions", @"user_games_activity",@"friends_games_activity",
                            nil];
```

I will really appreciate any help to solve this issue. I've been at it for a while.

Comment: pass the access_token also it automatically takes..

Comment: are you referring to the permissions for the access_token? They are user_friends, user_games_activity, email, publish_actions

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I've still not been able to solve the issue